# Move Purchased App from Windows Phone to iPhone

Tags: applications, ios, windows

My Windows Phone got stolen and I decided to get an iPhone 4s as a replacement.
I bought the Threema-App for WP 8.1.
Is there any possibility to get Threema for iOS 9.2.1 without having to buy it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the [Threema FAQ](https://threema.ch/en/faq)

> **Can I move the purchased app between operating systems?**
>
> Paid apps are sold for a commission by different providers (Apple, Google, Microsoft). They neither share nor forward data about their customers and licenses. Hence it is impossible to move licenses from one platform to another. Hence, when switching between Android, iOS or Windows phone, the app has to be purchased again for the new operating system.
> Please note that your contacts' verification levels cannot be moved when changing the operating system, whereas your Threema ID can be maintained.

You must buy it again on the [Apple App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/threema/id578665578?mt=8).

Answer (score 1):

I assume you know that the application on the Windows phone can't, itself, be installed on your new iPhone.

As to whether or not the manufacturer will allow you to "sidegrade" or not is a question only they can answer

Comment: Windows Phone to iPhone is no "sidegrade" it's definitely an upgrade :)

Comment: @RedEagle2000 i would not confirm that. it's just  an alternative - and can be jailbroken ;)